# Object Oriented Modeling Issue

Tags: class, relationship, entity-relationship

I have two tables

> 1= **cities**(cityId, CITY(string), *CountryId*)
>
> 2= **countries**(Id, CountryName(string))

I have two classes

```
public class CitiesList
{
    public int cityId{ get; set; }
    public int CountryId{ get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }

    public List<CitiesList> GetCity()
    {

        //get city list
        //
        //

        var query = from o in dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        
        select new CitiesList
        {
            CITYID = o.Field<int>("CITYID"),
            CITY = o.Field<string>("CITY")
        };

        List<CitiesList> lstDisplay = new List<CitiesList>();
        lstDisplay.AddRange(query);
        
        return lstDisplay;
    }
}

public class CountriesList
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public List<CountriesList> GetDisplayCountryList()
    {
        //code
        //
        //

        var query = from o in dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        select new CountriesList
        {
            CountryName = o.Field<string>("CountryName"),
            CountryId = o.Field<int>("CountryId")
        }
    }
}
```

All this code is working well....Now what if i want a join query to display data from both tables?because i can assign data only to one list at a tyme?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need a new data structure.  I'm envisioning something like a multi-map, where the key is the country and the value is a list of cities.

Data structures are good abstract data types, but I don't think the abstraction is complete.  Do you need another object somewhere besides lists or maps?